# Unable to access json values

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JSON array from ajax response but when I tried to access it field then it says undefined.
here is my JSON

```
[{"material_name":1042,"qty_per_piece":"30","material_qty_req":150},{"material_name":1043,"qty_per_piece":"20","material_qty_req":100},{"material_name":1041,"qty_per_piece":"10","material_qty_req":50}]
```

what i am trying its following

```
for(var j = 0; j<material.length; j++){
  var matName = material.material_name[j];
  alert(matName);
```

when i tried through following it shows undefined

```
for(var j = 0; j<material.length; j++){
  var material_names = material[j].material_name;
   alert(material_names);
```

Comment: You have to put the properties in the order you want to access them. You can't randomise the order. `material[j].material_name`

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one **was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers**.

Comment: material[j].material_name
it shows undefined

Comment: @HarunAnwar — http://jsbin.com/notikilizu/1/edit?js,console — no, it doesn't.

Comment: @HarunAnwar — Unless you forgot to parse the JSON. You should have provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```js
var material = [{"material_name":1042,"qty_per_piece":"30","material_qty_req":150},{"material_name":1043,"qty_per_piece":"20","material_qty_req":100},{"material_name":1041,"qty_per_piece":"10","material_qty_req":50}];

material.forEach(function(v,k){
    console.log(v.material_name);
});
```

Comment: @HarunAnwar — No, it doesn't.